# Why aren't my images displaying properly in HTML?

Tags: html, css, firebase, visual-studio, web

For some reason, my images are not loading in on my HTML document. I checked the link, and they are all valid. If I command click them it brings up the picture. I am not sure what else to do..
Here is the entire code of the website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="icon" href="/Users/evanmullen/Public/images/favIcon.ico">
        <title>Algobyte</title>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Mono:wght@100&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        </head>
    <body style="background: #efefef;">
        <div class="header" id="mainHeader">
            <img src="Users/evanmullen/Public/images/cover.png" alt="algobyte logo" width="20%">
        </div>

        <div class="app-section">
            <h3>Apps</h3>
        <!--QuickrTippr-->
            <p class="center">
                <a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/quickrtippr/id1551206999">
                    <img src="Users/evanmullen/Public/images/WebsiteQuickrTippr.png" alt="QuickrTippr picture" width="20%" class="app-picture"></a>

        <!--Identicryst-->
            <img src="/Users/evanmullen/Public/images/WebsiteIdenticryst.png" alt="Identicryst picture" width="20%" class="app-picture">
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="about-us">
            <h3>About Us</h3>
            <img src="Users/evanmullen/Public/images/bridge.jpg" alt="Bear Mountain Bridge, Cortlandt, NY" width="100%" class="center">
            <p class="center">
            We are a Hudson Valley, New York based software development company that strives to produce the highest quality software.
             </p>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

**I am using Firebase as my host.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is a pretty common thing.  It's not displaying because with the instructions you gave your file, the browser cannot find the image....heres what I do...I assume your using VS due to your tag, so inside the folder that your project is made in, upload or open the images you want to the same folder your index.html project is in.  Once the images are in the same folder you can just change the name of your images to src="imagename.png"  or jpeg or whatever you use.  If you dont want the images in the same folder, then just save them to another folder but in the same root folder of your project and copy the relative path name by right clicking and selecting "Copy relative path"  and incude that in your image element..it will look somthing like this...src="projects/image.png".   I hope that explains it and solves your issue.  Happy coding!

```
                <a href="https://apps.apple.com/us/app/quickrtippr/id1551206999">
          example ------> if in same folder as index.html          <img src="sophoto.png" alt="QuickrTippr picture" width="20%" class="app-picture"></a>
```